# Make two design or apk for android

Tags: android

Can we make two design or apk in android.Actually i'm facing the issue that i'm using a library which is only for greater than apk 17. So i want two design 1 for less than 17 apk and other one for greater than 17.How can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out the [Android docs on maintaining compatibility](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html). You can do things like provide alternate layout resources based on which version of the Android OS your user is on, or check system versions to decide which libraries/resources you can use in your code. Also, using the provided compat libraries help a lot with this issue as well.

For example, if you are wanting to use a certain library, but it only works on certain APIs, you could do something like this:

```
// Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // Call some material design APIs here
} else {
    // Implement this feature without material design
}
```

(code from the docs linked above)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create two folder under resources:

1) `res/layout/` (for layouts displayed on api 16 and below)

2) `res/layout-v17/` (for layouts displayed on api 17 and above)